# How does Java's record class implement synchronization?

Tags: java, java-16

Since Record class instance does not have the obj header which common Object instance has. But we can still use synchronization features like:

```
public record User(long id, String name, int age) {}

User user = new User(1, "name", 18);
synchronized (user) {
    user.wait();
    System.out.println("test");
}
```

Would there be a process like common Object instance from light weight lock to heavy lock transformation?

Comment: An instance of a record is an object like any other object, so you can synchronize on it just like you can on any other object.

Comment: Where did you read that record does not have a flatlock in its metadata?

Comment: When you make a bold statement like record instances had no object header, you should provide a source.

Comment: A lot of people seem to be confused between records (a feature that is in Java now) and primitive classes (a feature coming to a future Java via Project Valhalla.)  They have a lot in common, and there has been a lot of noise in the community that conflates the two, so I suspect s/he has been influenced by that.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Java's `record` classes are ordinary classes, with an object identity and all the things that come with them (like a monitor.)

That said, if you find yourself synchronizing on a `record`, you're probably doing something wrong; the state of records is shallowly immutable (all fields are final), so it's not clear why you would be locking on the record.